# Getting NullPointerException performing unit-testing with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Please don't mark it as duplicate, I am unable to fix this issue.

I am writing unit testing using *Mockito*. While executing the test case, I am getting `NullPointerException` on the `@Autowired bean` of `MainTemplate class`.

Code:

```
public abstract class Template{

  abstract public boolean isEven(String input);

  private String getName(String initial){
    return "INIT"+initial;
  }

  final public void run(String input){
   isEven(input);
   getName(input);

  }
}
```

Implementation of Template:

```
public class MainTemplate extends Template{

 @Autowired
 private UserUtil userUtil;

    @Override
    public boolean isEven(String input){
      return userUtil.getResult(input);  //GETTING NullPointerException here..
    }
}
```

Bean configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration{
  @Bean
  public Template getBean(){
     return new MainTemplate();
  }
}

@Service
public class Executor{
 @Autowired
 private BeanConfiguration beanConfig;

 public void execute(){
   beanConfig.getBean().run("sample input");
 }

}
```

Unit testing class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MainTemplateTest{

  @InjectMocks
  private MainTemplate mainTemplate;

  @Mock
  private UserUtil userUtil;

  @Test
  public void isEvenTest(){

    Mockito.when(userUtil.getResult(anyString())).thenReturn(true);

    mainTemplate.isEven("input string");
  }
}
```

I am getting NullPointerException while running the above test.
Getting NullPointerException on:

```
    @Override
    public boolean isEven(String input){
      return userUtil.getResult(input);  //GETTING NullPointerException, while calling from mock method
    }
```

Comment: `@RnWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` <- typo (RunWith _u_ is missing)?

Comment: @lugiorgi - Thanks fixed the typo

Comment: Hey @mayankbisht, would you please provide the first few lines of the NullPointerException stack trace, to help us better diagnose the issue?

Comment: Are you running this with junit4 or junit5? I think in junit5 you do not use RunWith but ExtendWith.

Answer (score 1):

First, decide if you want mockito runner (Junit 4)/ extension (Junit 5) or Spring runner / extension (see @SpringBootTest)

I believe that for this test, Mockito extension is the way to go - the test will spin up and execute faster, and will be less fragile to changes in Spring config.

**Mockito Extension version**

- remove @SpringBootTest
- use constructor injection

**SpringBootTest version**

- remove @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
- do not use @InjectMocks, use @Autowired instead
- do not use @Mock, use @MockBean instead
- field injection is still a code smell, do yourself a favor and use constructor injection